# Serving static HTML files without extension in Django

Tags: django

I want to serve static html files at development. I want every `file.html` to be served at `/file`.

It's clear that in production static files should be served via Nginx or something else.

But how to do it at development, in an elegant way? It would me amazing with `index.html` at `/`, also.

What i have now:

In `urls.py`

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    def index(request):
        return render(request, 'index.html')
    urlpatterns += patterns('', url(r'^$', index))
    urlpatterns += static('/', document_root=settings.BASE_DIR+'/static/')
```

And also in `settings.py`

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/'),
)
```

Comment: TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'), )

Comment: also your static files settings should be there I guess

Comment: @HassenPy Sorry, added the relevant fragment of `settings.py`

Comment: And have you tried changing your `STATIC_URL` to `/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write a view that handles adding the `.html` and configure a URLConf to use it.

**The view**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.staticfiles.views import serve


def serve_html(request, file_name):
    if not file_name:
        file_name = 'index'

    file_path = '{}.html'.format(file_name)

    # Use Django staticfiles's serve view.
    return serve(request, file_path)
```

**The URLConf**

```
url(r'^(?P<file_name>.*)$', serve_html)
```

It is important to put the URLConf last in your `urls.py` otherwise, it will catch **all** requests and your other URLConfs will not be reached.

Comment: Wonderful.

Also, I have `/static` directory not at app level, but at project level, so for `serve()` to work I had to set `STATICFILES_DIRS` in `settings.py` properly.

Comment: @o2genum Indeed, the answer assumes that your static files are correctly set up ;)